# python list is out of range at iteration 14?

Tags: python

i have a list of indexes that point a term in database

Here is my code:

```
for doc in TSS:
    tokens = word_tokenize(doc[1])
    tokens = [token.lower() for token in tokens if len(token) > 2]
    tokens = [token for token in tokens if token not in words]
    tokens = [stemmer.stem(token) for token in tokens]
    final_tokens.extend(tokens)
    sql = """SELECT id_term FROM tss_terms WHERE tss_terms.term IN %s"""
    pram = [final_tokens]
    cursor.execute(sql, pram)
    ids = list(cursor.fetchall())
    count = 0
    data[doc[1]] = {'tf': {}, 'ntf': {}}
    for token in final_tokens:
        data[doc[1]]['tf'][token] = freq(token,final_tokens)
        data[doc[1]]['ntf'][token] = tf(token,final_tokens)
        query = """INSERT INTO tss_term_freq(id_term,id_doc,tf,normalized_tf)VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
        param = [ids[count],doc[0],data[doc[1]]['tf'][token],data[doc[1]]['ntf'][token]]
        #cursor.execute(query, param)
        count = count + 1
    del final_tokens[:]
    print count
```

the `ids` list always get `error : list index out of range` at the 14th iteration.

the values of TSS[13] are like this:

```
(5927L, 'PERHITUNGAN POHON KELAPA SAWIT PADA CITRA FOTO UDARA\r\nYANG BERBASIS BENTUK MAHKOTA POHON')
```

then the values of TSS[14] are like this:

```
(6698L, 'SINKRONISASI WAKTU METER LISTRIK BERDASARKAN GLOBAL POSITIONING SYSTEM (GPS) PADA SUPERVISORY CONTROL AND DATA ACQUISITION (SCADA) BERBASIS WEB')
```

TSS contains document ids and titles of thesis in my university

can anyone show my mistake and fix it?

Please help :(

Comment: Which line is the problem?

Comment: Share the stack trace and the value of `TSS[13]` and `TSS[14]`

Comment: the param line is the problem
i commented the line below so that it doesn't execute the query command

Comment: Based on this much information, we can only tell you that among param = `ids[count]`, `doc[0]`, `data[doc[1]]['tf'][token]`, and `data[doc[1]]['ntf'][token]` any of the value is missing.

Comment: Why not print each of these values and check by yourself what is going wrong? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the list "id" is declared is wrong.
I didnt get what you are doing there.
But if want to store all the values returned by fetchall() function then use for loop for doing it.
Declare an empty list id.
id = [ ]
Use a for loop for taking all the values.
And to save the value in list use 
id.append(value)

Comment: What you are suggesting does exactly the same thing as already existing part of code. I wouldn't be surprised if existing wasn't even more efficient.

Comment: wow that only very little difference affects so much.. Thanks anyway :)